# How to add an animation to android wear watch face?

Tags: animation, wear-os

i'm building a watch face for android wear and i built some nice animation that i want to add in the watch face. Btw i didn't understood where i have to add my code to load the animation from XML and start/stop them.

This is the java code:

```html
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.udellent.layoutwatchface;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.CanvasWatchFaceService;
import android.support.wearable.watchface.WatchFaceStyle;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowInsets;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Digital watch face with seconds. In ambient mode, the seconds aren't displayed. On devices with
 * low-bit ambient mode, the text is drawn without anti-aliasing in ambient mode.
 */
public class LayoutFaceService extends CanvasWatchFaceService {
    private static final Typeface NORMAL_TYPEFACE =
            Typeface.create(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL);

    /**
     * Update rate in milliseconds for interactive mode. We update once a second since seconds are
     * displayed in interactive mode.
     */
    private static final long INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1);

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new Engine();
    }

    private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {
        static final int MSG_UPDATE_TIME = 0;

        /**
         * Handler to update the time periodically in interactive mode.
         */
        final Handler mUpdateTimeHandler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                switch (message.what) {
                    case MSG_UPDATE_TIME:
                        invalidate();
                        if (shouldTimerBeRunning()) {
                            long timeMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            long delayMs = INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS
                                    - (timeMs % INTERACTIVE_UPDATE_RATE_MS);
                            mUpdateTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE_TIME, delayMs);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        final BroadcastReceiver mTimeZoneReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                mTime.clear(intent.getStringExtra("time-zone"));
                mTime.setToNow();
            }
        };

        boolean mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver = false;

        boolean mAmbient;

        Time mTime;

        float mXOffset = 0;
        float mYOffset = 0;

        private int specW, specH;
        private View myLayout;
        private TextView day, date, month, hour, minute, second;
        private final Point displaySize = new Point();

        /**
         * Whether the display supports fewer bits for each color in ambient mode. When true, we
         * disable anti-aliasing in ambient mode.
         */
        boolean mLowBitAmbient;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onCreate(holder);

            setWatchFaceStyle(new WatchFaceStyle.Builder(LayoutFaceService.this)
                    .setCardPeekMode(WatchFaceStyle.PEEK_MODE_SHORT)
                    .setBackgroundVisibility(WatchFaceStyle.BACKGROUND_VISIBILITY_INTERRUPTIVE)
                    .setShowSystemUiTime(false)
                    .build());
            Resources resources = LayoutFaceService.this.getResources();

            mTime = new Time();

            // Inflate the layout that we're using for the watch face
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            myLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.watchface, null);

            // Load the display spec - we'll need this later for measuring myLayout
            Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                    .getDefaultDisplay();
            display.getSize(displaySize);

            // Find some views for later use
            day = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.day);
            date = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.date);
            month = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.month);
            hour = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.hour);
            minute = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.minute);
            second = (TextView) myLayout.findViewById(R.id.second);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);

            if (visible) {
                registerReceiver();

                // Update time zone in case it changed while we weren't visible.
                mTime.clear(TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
                mTime.setToNow();
            } else {
                unregisterReceiver();
            }

            // Whether the timer should be running depends on whether we're visible (as well as
            // whether we're in ambient mode), so we may need to start or stop the timer.
            updateTimer();
        }

        private void registerReceiver() {
            if (mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver) {
                return;
            }
            mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver = true;
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
            LayoutFaceService.this.registerReceiver(mTimeZoneReceiver, filter);
        }

        private void unregisterReceiver() {
            if (!mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver) {
                return;
            }
            mRegisteredTimeZoneReceiver = false;
            LayoutFaceService.this.unregisterReceiver(mTimeZoneReceiver);
        }

        @Override
        public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
            super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);

            if (insets.isRound()) {
                // Shrink the face to fit on a round screen
                mYOffset = mXOffset = displaySize.x * 0.1f;
                displaySize.y -= 2 * mXOffset;
                displaySize.x -= 2 * mXOffset;
            } else {
                mXOffset = mYOffset = 0;
            }

            // Recompute the MeasureSpec fields - these determine the actual size of the layout
            specW = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(displaySize.x, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
            specH = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(displaySize.y, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPropertiesChanged(Bundle properties) {
            super.onPropertiesChanged(properties);
            mLowBitAmbient = properties.getBoolean(PROPERTY_LOW_BIT_AMBIENT, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimeTick() {
            super.onTimeTick();
            invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAmbientMode) {
            super.onAmbientModeChanged(inAmbientMode);
            if (mAmbient != inAmbientMode) {
                mAmbient = inAmbientMode;

                // Show/hide the seconds fields
                if (inAmbientMode) {
                    second.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    myLayout.findViewById(R.id.second_label).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    myLayout.findViewById(R.id.second_label).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                // Switch between bold & normal font
                Typeface font = Typeface.create("sans-serif-condensed",
                        inAmbientMode ? Typeface.NORMAL : Typeface.BOLD);
                ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) myLayout;
                for (int i = group.getChildCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    // We only get away with this because every child is a TextView
                    ((TextView) group.getChildAt(i)).setTypeface(font);
                }

                invalidate();
            }

            // Whether the timer should be running depends on whether we're visible (as well as
            // whether we're in ambient mode), so we may need to start or stop the timer.
            updateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {
            // Get the current Time
            mTime.setToNow();

            // Apply it to the date fields
            day.setText(String.format("%ta", mTime.toMillis(false)));
            date.setText(String.format("%02d", mTime.monthDay));
            month.setText(String.format("%tb", mTime.toMillis(false)));

            // Apply it to the time fields
            hour.setText(String.format("%02d", mTime.hour));
            minute.setText(String.format("%02d", mTime.minute));
            if (!mAmbient) {
                second.setText(String.format("%02d", mTime.second));
            }

            // Update the layout
            myLayout.measure(specW, specH);
            myLayout.layout(0, 0, myLayout.getMeasuredWidth(), myLayout.getMeasuredHeight());

            // Draw it to the Canvas
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            canvas.translate(mXOffset, mYOffset);
            myLayout.draw(canvas);
        }

        /**
         * Starts the {@link #mUpdateTimeHandler} timer if it should be running and isn't currently
         * or stops it if it shouldn't be running but currently is.
         */
        private void updateTimer() {
            mUpdateTimeHandler.removeMessages(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
            if (shouldTimerBeRunning()) {
                mUpdateTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_UPDATE_TIME);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Returns whether the {@link #mUpdateTimeHandler} timer should be running. The timer should
         * only run when we're visible and in interactive mode.
         */
        private boolean shouldTimerBeRunning() {
            return isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode();
        }
    }
}
```

I normally load the animation with :

```html
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.myanimation);
      image.startAnimation(animation);
```

If u kindly can help me would be great... tnx a lot

Answer (score 0):

When I was playing around animation, I found out that "standart" methods, like "startAnimation" are linked with callbacks from ViewTree, whitch says, when the view is drawn or redrawn. Using .draw method directly will not produce this callbacks. 
So, you have an option to explore the inner structure of Animation class and create fake structure to make it belive, it's working in default way.
Or (my choice) work with layout properties manually.

Well, it's something like this (just a draft to show an idea)

```
View yourLayer = ..... // provide the view you wanna play with
int i=0;
Runnable moveToLeftAnimation = new Runnable(){ 
   public void run(){
       yourLayer.setPadding(0, i+10, 0, 0);
       new Handler().post(this, 1000); 
   }
};
new Handler().post(moveToLeftAnimation, 1000)
```

But if you have some complicated layer like heavvy ImageView, it will spend way too much memory and processor time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you explain me what you mean for "work with layout properties manually" please?

Comment: Well, it's something like this

Comment: Tnx Ivan but i have different animations that use also interpolator. I tryed a way similar to yours using invalidate() to run the animation. BTW the result is not as good as using the xml

Comment: Yep, I just marked for myself that animation for wear is somewhat pain in the back :)

Comment: I agree, i can't solve it. I need an animated background and some other objects that moves indipendently